# In Tensorflow, is there an op / are there ops to accept a tensor (of filenames) and output images?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to be able to read in batches of images. However, these batches must be constructed by a python script (they cannot be placed into a file ahead of time for various reasons). What's the most efficient way, in tensorflow to do the following:

(1) Provided: A python list of B variable-length strings that point to images, all have the same size. B is the batch size. 
(2) For each string, load the image it corresponds to, and apply a random crop of 5% (the crop is random but the size of the crop is fixed)
(3) Concatenate the images together into a tensor of size B x H x W x 3

If this is not possible, does anyone have any benchmarks / data on the efficiency loss of loading and preprocessing the images in python then placing them into a queue? I assume the net will run considerably faster if image loading / preprocessing is done internally on tensorflow.

Comment: Can you post the python script that constructs the batches? I don't understand exactly what has to be done by this script: does it choose which images to put into the batch or does it construct the filenames or something else?

Comment: The script that generates the batches is pretty elaborate and probably fairly unhelpful. The reason it must exist is because the data's labels correspond to relations _between_ training examples, not the training examples themselves. The script ensure that is preserved. Thus is "constructs" batches by assembling groups of filenames in a specific way, and then computes the appropriate labels.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understand your problem:

- you have some images
- you have a function `sample_batch()` which returns a batch of filenames of size `B`
- you want to read the images corresponding to these filenames and preprocess them
- finally you output a batch of these examples

---

```py
input = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='Input')
queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity, tf.string, [()], name='Queue')
enqueue_op = queue.enqueue_many(input)

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
filename, content = reader.read(queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, channels=3)

# Preprocessing
image = tf.random_crop(image, [H, W, 3])
image = tf.to_float(image)
batch_image = tf.train.batch([image], batch_size=B, name='Batch')
output = inference(batch_image)
```

---

Then in the session, you have to run the enqueue operation with the filenames from your `sample_batch()`function:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.train.start_queue_runners()
  for i in range(NUM_STEPS):
    batch_filenames = sample_batch()
    sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={input: batch_filenames})
    sess.run(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the images as a byte array you can use something similar to this in your graph:

```
 jpegs = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(None))
 images = tf.map_fn(lambda jpeg : your_processing_fn(jpeg), jpegs,
                   dtype=tf.float32)
 logits = your_inference_model(images,labels)
```

where your_processing_fn is a function which receives a jpeg tensor of bytes, decodes, resizes and crops it and returns a image of H x W x 3

You need the latest version of tensorflow as map_fn is not in 0.8 and below.